# Upgrade from TYPO3 7.6.32 to 8.7.32 "stuck" at 93%

Tags: typo3

I've been upgrading TYPO3 on my webapplication and came to the following issue:
I can execute the tasks provided by the Upgrade Wizard 'till it is at 93% with the task "Add the default Extension Manager database tables" left. When I execute this task the wizard returns "Update successful" but afterwards it is still at 93% and the task appears to be still open (which is also true when I execute this task earlier in the upgrade process).

Is this a known issue and is there a fix? As far as I can tell everything works properly so it isn't really a problem, but still annoying.

Comment: Same issue here

Answer (score 0):

To skip the step 'Add the default Extension Manager database tables' edit the file typo3_src-8.7.32\typo3\sysext\install\Classes\Updates\ExtensionManagerTables.php and change the function getUpdateStatements() to

```
protected function getUpdateStatements(){
    return [];
}
```

The next step is buggy too. Just do it once and then edit the file typo3_src-8.7.32\typo3\sysext\install\Classes\Updates\FinalDatabaseSchemaUpdate.php and change the function checkForUpdates() to

```
public function checkForUpdate(&$description): bool{
    return false;
}
```

You should only do this, if your goal is to update further more to version 9 and so on. This kind of Code editing is normaly not a good idea.